# fatal error Xcode 9.4 beta - all red cannot access files

Tags: ios, xcode

PLEASE! can somebody, anybody out here lead me to as what this is about ? I was trying to access my pod within the terminal, and the next thing i know, this comes up when i opened my project. All the classes are Red - and i cannot click on any of them. Has this happened to anybody ?? Im new to iOS and i seriously hope i did not just delete or mess up a project ive been working on for a whole month. Please and thanks

Before this error - all of the check marks such as orientation - and such were all filled out. i seriously have no clue what to do, and i believe im messing things up even more by clicking around !!! SH**^%%TTT
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Try to run `pod install`. 2. Are you sure you opened the `.xcworkspace` file?

Comment: I will try that. I had to leave for an hour but as soon as I get back. And honestly, in attempting to fix it, I did so much clicking around, I even messed with the “identity & type” of the project folder. I feel so stupid right now

Comment: But to answer your question, yes I believe I was in the workspace project. It shows that in the screen shots at least

Comment: I do also remember - I Right clicked my project and chose “show in finder” when it the folder it was apart of- I renamed it. And next thing I know this happened- do you think that could be an issue? Idk because I named it back to the first name but this is still showing

Comment: Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50168614/3151675).

Comment: I will check as soon as I get back to my lPtop. Thank you so much for the help and direction

Comment: you probably renamed or moved the folder containing the project. quit xcode and open the project again from Finder

Comment: @the4kman it worked. That’s again for the positive  direction