# what does the red file name mean in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Here is the screen shot of a project in Xcode:

[image]

There are a few file name in red. Does it spell trouble? How to fix them?

Comment: Xcode thinks it should exist, but it actually doesn’t. Should be ok in your case though - once you build, the files should be generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Files in Xcode not working (names in red)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889651/files-in-xcode-not-working-names-in-red)